# Thread Safety Multiple Approaches

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, java-threads

I'm developing an application which is meant to work in multi threading environment. The code sample looks like -

```
private Map<String, Account> accountMap;    // Account is a POJO
     
public Double processTransaction(Transaction transaction) {     // Transaction is a POJO
        Account account = accountMap.get(transaction.getAccountNumber());

        synchronized (account) {
            TransactionType mode = transaction.getTransactionType();
            switch (mode) {
                case DEPOSIT:
                    Double balance = account.getBalance();
                    balance += transaction.getBalance();
                    account.setBalance(balance);
                    accountMap.put(transaction.getAccountNumber(), account);
                    break;

                case WITHDRAW:
                    Double presentBalance = account.getBalance();
                    if(presentBalance < transaction.getBalance()) {
                        // throw some exception
                    }
                    presentBalance = presentBalance - transaction.getBalance();
                    account.setBalance(presentBalance);
                    accountMap.put(transaction.getAccountNumber(), account);
                    break;

            }
        }
        return accountMap.get(transaction.getAccountNumber()).getBalance();
    }
```

The other possible approach could be defining `accountMap as a concurrent HashMap` instead of using `synchronized` block.

My question is, are the above approaches correct and what else approaches could be used to ensure thread safety?

Comment: What precise sequence of events does the `synchronized` block avoid? Does a `ConcurrentHashMap` protect against that sequence?

Comment: What's the point of doing `accountMap.put(transaction.getAccountNumber(), account)` on every transaction? And how is synchronizing on an individual `account` supposed to protect the whole map?

Comment: If the intent of `processTransaction` is to return the account balance as a result exclusively of the provided transaction then it would potentially return incorrect results in a multi-threaded environment.  This is because the final `getBalance` is outside the critical section and is vulnerable to other threads performing transactions _after_ the provided transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calls to `put()` are redundant because the mapping is already present. It looks like the only thing this method really does is adjust the balance of an individual account. I would have `Account` provide an adjustment method that synchronizes internally:

```
public synchronized double adjustBalance(double delta) {
    return this.balance += delta;
}
```

Then call it with a simple `if` to negate the amount:

```
public Double processTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
    double delta = transaction.getBalance();
    if (transaction.getTransactionType() == TransactionType.WITHDRAW) {
        delta = -delta;
    }
    return accountMap.get(transaction.getAccountNumber()).adjustBalance(delta);
}
```

Comment: Great solution, probably throwing exception in `adjustBalance` is missing for insufficient funds. Also don't foget to make `puts` visible to `processTransaction`. If puts could be done at runtime you have to do something with it.

Comment: @gdomo You mean puts to the map? It could be an immutable map initialized safely, or it could be modified in some concurrent thread and would need to be a ConcurrentMap or the like. There's no indication in the question as to how it's populated and managed.

Comment: This solution is good if you're just adjusting the balance of one account.
But if there are two accounts you'd need to withdraw from one and add to another, then you need the transaction context to envelop both actions.

I personally would prefer using a ReadWriteLock (since synchronized has bad characteristics including deadlocks in some cases), and we'd need to acquire the write lock for both accounts then write to one and then to the other.

Of course, in the real world we avoid this mess by just delegating this to database transactions.

Comment: @gdomo the original code doesn't show any requirement to detect overdrawn accounts.

Comment: @AminM I don't see anything in the question about transferring between accounts. And I don't see why it would be necessary to synchronize on both simultaneously. And I don't see how ReadWriteLock would prevent deadlocking in that scenario.

Comment: @shmosel bank accounts don't happen in a vacuum. You need to ensure that two transactions can't withdraw from the same account at the same time (unless you want a process to detect overdraft and then undo transactions). ReadWriteLock can allow people to read the account balance without having to synchronize. And it has a timeout feature that can detect and mitigate deadlocks (of course, real deadlock prevention necessitates that you always lock the objects in the same order). If you don't lock both accounts then a failure to write to one may land you in a situation where the money ends up lost

Comment: This is also why a database solution is better.. because it has automatic rollback. Doing bank transactions without rollback is dangerous.

Comment: @AminM You're making a lot of assumptions about what's probably meant to be an abstract exercise. There was no mention of an overdraft protection requirement. And it might be an ATM for all we know. And there's no need (at least in the code presented) to look up the balance without modification. And if there was, a simple getter with a `volatile` field would work equally well.

Comment: The question is a specific question about Java synchronization, not a request for a treatise on multiuser computer systems.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are trying to achieve with the synchronised block.
With `synchronized (account)`, you are locking the account object and making sure that only thread can make changes to that object. So there is no need to put the object back into the map again.

But the real issue is you are getting the object outside the `synchronized` block. So any other thread(call it T2) can access the same object and make modification before T1 starts executing the `synchronized` block.

If you are ok with that kind of modification/ or if you are sure that the `accountMap` is not used anywhere else, it might work.

But the best case would be to lock on the map itself. And yes, a `ConcurrentHashMap` will perform better if you are locking on the entire map object.

Comment: There is no issue with getting the account outside the `synchronized` block, because the change to the balance in the account is protected by the `synchronized` block. Of course if there is other code we haven't seen using `accountMap`, there could be concurrency issues, but that is clearly out of the scope of the question.

Comment: Locking on the Map is a terrible idea -- then only one thread can be active in `processTransaction`, when in fact we can have one thread *per account* active with no concurrency problems. If we lock the entire Map, why would `ConcurrentHashMap` be necessary, or perform better? There is no need to use `ConcurrentHashMap` in this scenario, especially if we remove the redundant `put` calls.